# Finding the equation for image of a map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the morphism $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^2$ given by $f(t) = (t^n,(1-t)^n)$.  What is the defining equation of the image?  Is there a systematic way to do this?

Comment: What are $\mathbb A^1$ and $\mathbb A^2$ here?

Comment: Affine space of dimension $1$ and $2$.  Just think $\mathbb C^1$ and $\mathbb C^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The area of math that deals with this sort of thing is called elimination theory. Given the equations $x=t^n,y=(1-t)^n$, we want to eliminate $t$ from these equations. We can determine the unique up to scaling polynomial which vanishes on your curve as $\operatorname{Res}_t(x-t^n,y-(1-t)^n)$ where $\operatorname{Res}$ is the resultant.

The resultant can be computed as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of the two polynomials (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition) for the definition). In our case, this matrix is somewhat nice: it's a $2n\times 2n$ matrix, where $A$ the upper left $n\times n$ block is the identity matrix and $C$ the lower left block matrix is the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with $x$ along the diagonal. The right-hand blocks are somewhat less nice to describe, but they're both triangular matrices: $B$ the upper right $n\times n$ matrix is lower-triangular with $(-1)^n$ on the diagonal, and $D$ the lower right matrix is upper triangular with $1+y$ on the diagonal. Since the two lower blocks commute, we can compute the determinant of the Sylvester matrix as $\det(AD-BC)=\det(D-xB)$. Unfortunately, I don't see any further simplifications to make to this computation in general, and for instance checking what this determinant is over the first few values of $n$ doesn't give me a pattern that I can generalize. It's clear that these equations should be symmetric in $x$ and $y$ (think of the involution $t\mapsto 1-t$), and the highest degree term should be $(x-(-1)^ny)^n$ based on the diagonal, but I don't see much of a pattern after that.

If you want to look at the results of the resultant for various values of $n$, I'd ask a computer algebra system to do it for you. For instance, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx-t%5E4%2Cy-%281-t%29%5E4%2Ct%5D) will do it for you - the linked example is the $n=4$ case, and you can change it around by changing the exponents in the box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690)

```
R=QQ[t,x,y,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 1]
I1=ideal(x-t,y-(1-t))
toString (gens gb I1)_0_0
-- x+y-1

I2=ideal(x-t^2,y-(1-t)^2)
toString (gens gb I2)_0_0
-- x^2-2*x*y+y^2-2*x-2*y+1

I3=ideal(x-t^3,y-(1-t)^3)
toString (gens gb I3)_0_0
-- x^3+3*x^2*y+3*x*y^2+y^3-3*x^2+21*x*y-3*y^2+3*x+3*y-1

I4=ideal(x-t^4,y-(1-t)^4)
toString (gens gb I4)_0_0
-- x^4-4*x^3*y+6*x^2*y^2-4*x*y^3+y^4-4*x^3-124*x^2*y-124*x*y^2-4*y^3+6*x^2-124*x*y+6*y^2-4*x-4*y+1
```

The leading terms seem to be $(x+y)^n$ for $n$ odd and $(x-y)^n$ for $n$ even.

In geogebra

[image: I4]